# Error when running form code from different sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a Form with many Subs. Workbook has many sheets. When I start the Form when the active sheet is `CodesSheet`, using any of the `For Each rCell` in the code below work OK. When I start the code from a different sheet, code runs OK when using the second line -`.Range("L2:L4125")`-, but fails with the first one -`.Range(Cells(2, 12), Cells(LastRowCodes, 12))`.

Message is `Run time error 1004 - Method Range of object _worksheet failed`. But on debug, mouse over `LastRowCodes` shows the proper value (4125).

Anyone can spot the error?

```
For Each rCell In CodesSheet.Range(Cells(2, 12), Cells(LastRowCodes, 12)) '-->Error here, although LastRowCodes is correct
'For Each rCell In CodesSheet.Range("L2:L4125") '--> If using this instead of the above, no error

    'Do Stuff

Next rCell
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Cells` without a `Worksheet` reference means `ActiveSheet` is assumed.

Use a `With...End With` block to fully qualify the `Worksheet` - note the periods.

```
With CodesSheet
    For each rCell in .Range(.Cells(2, 12), .Cells(LastRowCodes, 12))
        ....
    Next rCell
End With
```

Comment: Thats it! I thought the previous `CodesSheet.Range` was enought. I've been dealing with this silliness for hours, before posting here. Thanks a lot.